# parseInt with Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've come across something a bit odd.

I'm trying to parse a string with a time in ( e.g. "12:00", "13:30") into two separate integers. 
I tried this:

```
timeString = "12:00"
[hours, minutes] = timeString.split(":").map(parseInt)
```

But minutes comes out as NaN

I thought there was a problem with parseInt taking in "00", but when I tried parseInt("00") in the console I get 0.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Because `parseInt()` takes an second (optional) argument, and Array#map provides a second argument to the passed function. You can use `.map(parseFloat)`, `.map(Number)`, `.map(Math.floor)` or `.map(int)` (something I usually have laying around `const int = v => 0|v, uint = v => v>>>0;` )

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls the function with three arguments:

1. The current element
2. The current index
3. The array

This means that in the following snippet, `parseInt` is called with `"00"` and `1` (which is the index):

```
timeString = "12:00"
[hours, minutes] = timeString.split(":").map(parseInt)
```

The second argument to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) has to be greater than `2`, otherwise `NaN` will be returned.

That's what happens here.

To solve that, you could use:

```
timeString = "12:00"
[hours, minutes] = timeString.split(":").map(v => parseInt(v, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt takes 2 arguments, `parseInt(numberOrString, numberBase)` which can be used for binary strings, hexadecimal strings etc. `.map` takes a callback with the first 2 arguments being `.map(item, index)`.
So basically you're calling `parseInt("00", 1)` which returns NaN.

Change your code to

`timeString = "12:00"
var [hours, minutes] = timeString.split(":").map(i => parseInt(i))`